# Different background for section page in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, sectioning

On this picture you can see a titlepage, a section page and a content page done in Powerpoint:

[image: powerpoint template]

How to modify this code so that the section page has the background shown on the image? I can do the text positioning by myself later on.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz, datetime, textpos}
\yyyymmdddate \renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}

\definecolor{MedianBrown}{RGB}{119,95,85}
\definecolor{MedianLightBrown}{RGB}{235,221,195}
\definecolor{MedianLightBlue}{RGB}{148,182,210}
\definecolor{MedianOrange}{RGB}{221,128,71}
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=MedianLightBrown}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=MedianOrange}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=MedianBrown}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \ifnum\thepage>1\relax% Not the title page
        \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,8) rectangle(0.8,8.3);
        \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (0.9,8) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8.3);
  \else% Title page
      \fill[color=MedianBrown] (0,1.5) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
      \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,0.1) rectangle(3.45,1.4);
      \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (3.55,0.1) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.4); 
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
    \begin{textblock*}{12cm}(3cm,2.8cm)
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=8cm]{title page header}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor{title}\inserttitle%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \end{textblock*}
    \begin{textblock*}{12cm}(-0.5cm,4.9cm)
        \begin{beamercolorbox}{date}
          \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{textblock*}
    \begin{textblock*}{9cm}(3cm,4.9cm)
        \begin{beamercolorbox}{author}
          \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{textblock*}
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
    \vskip0.3cm
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{frametitle}
        \insertframetitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\author{Author Name}
\title{Quite A Long Title For A Simple Beamer Presentation}
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}
\frame{\maketitle}
\section{Introduction}
\frame{\sectionpage}
\begin{frame}{My presentation is about\ldots}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some stuff
\item And some other stuff
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To clarify, You want the `\sectionpage` background color to be MedianBrown, right?

Comment: @dcmst No, I want the section page to have the background as shown in the second slide of the PowerPoint example at the top. Essentially similar to the normal background but the blue rectangle height is bigger so that the section title fits on it, and the orange rectangle to the left has the same height.

Comment: @dcmst The slight brownish background of the sectionpage in Powerpoint are actually thin stripes, but that can be ignored.

Comment: Is the question about installing a different background on certain conditions or about how to draw the graphics with tikz?

Comment: @Bordaigorl Installing a different background on certain conditions.

Comment: The problem is that the `section page` template gets "called" within a frame but the `background` template can only be changed before starting the frame. Also, setting flags patching `\sectionpage` probably wont work because it would set them after the background is typeset...would you be happy to just define a new macro `\sectionframe` instead of the std one?

Comment: @Bordaigorl That could do. Maybe in the future Beamer itself should provide a way to do this.

Comment: @Bordaigorl The `section page` template could also "delete" the previous background with a white rectangle.

Comment: This can be achieved using a custom frame definition with the desired background embedded. You will have to call `\mysectionpage` instead of `\sectionpage`. Would you be interested in such a solution? I'm asking because I'm under the impression that you want to improve your code and not a totally different approach.

Comment: @dcmst Defining a custom sectionpage macro is what Bordaigorl recommended above, and yes that's totally okay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll add my answer too, the approach is the same of Bordaigorl but with less code involved.

The idea is to create another `\setbeamertemplate{background}` and embed it into a custom command to be used instead of `\frame{\sectionpage}`

The custom command will redefine the background and then the `section page` template. Just as an example I used a `tikzpicture` to reposition the section head.

This is the custom command:

```
\newcommand{\mysectionpage}{
    \begingroup
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}                                         %edit this tikzpicture to customize the size and colors of the background rectangles
            \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
            \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,7) rectangle(0.8,8);     
            \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (0.9,7) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \setbeamercolor{section page}{fg=white}
    \setbeamertemplate{section page}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                             %edit this tikzpicture to customize the appearance of the section heading
        \node[overlay] at (1,2) {\insertsectionhead};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \frame{\sectionpage}
    \endgroup
}
```

The rest of your preamble code stays untouched. The body of the document will look like this:

```
\begin{document}
\frame{\maketitle}
\section{Introduction}
\mysectionpage                                 %new code
\begin{frame}{My presentation is about\ldots}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some stuff
\item And some other stuff
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: In my answer I was suggesting the commands producing the titleframe because it leads to a more flexible approach than producing different backgrounds by testing the page number: what if you want another title page later on? It is also more uniform since both section and title pages get generated in the same way.
Do you know of any hook in `frame` to install the backgrounds from within the frame?

Comment: @Bordaigorl Why your pres. should have more than one title? My assumption was: 1 title -> 1 pres. However if you really want to you can replicate my approach for the frame with the title, it's just a copy-paste exercise. Then you will have also uniformity. Anyway, IMO the perfect solution would be to extend the OP approach with another `if`. Smthg like `if this is a sectionpage then install this background`. But I don't know how you could test for a `sectionpage`, I'll research it when I have time (maybe I'll post a question too)

Comment: I mention flags in my answer for that reason: you need to set them before starting the frame if you want the background template to react accordingly. If you stick with the `\sectiontitle` macro you can do that very easily. I can write another answer if you are interested

Answer (score 3):

Another option following the same pattern as the MWE which uses conditionals to define the background once and forall.
I do not like this approach as it is not very modular but since @dcmst asked here's a solution with conditionals.

First let's introduce a new conditional for section pages and set it to false

```
\newif\ifinsectionframe
\insectionframefalse
```

Now we can change the `background` template as follows

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \ifnum\thepage>1\relax% Not the title page
    \ifinsectionframe%
        \node {Some background}; %% INSERT YOUR GRAPHICS HERE
    \else%
        \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,8) rectangle(0.8,8.3);
        \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (0.9,8) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8.3);
    \fi%
  \else% Title page
      \fill[color=MedianBrown] (0,1.5) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
      \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,0.1) rectangle(3.45,1.4);
      \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (3.55,0.1) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.4); 
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Then we can create a `\sectionframe` macro that sets the corresponding flag before creating a frame with the section page:

```
\newcommand{\sectionframe}{
  \insectionframetrue
  \frame{\sectionpage}
  \insectionframefalse
}
```

Then if you use `\sectionframe` instead of `\frame{\sectionpage}` you have the desired effect.

A note on the conditional to detect the title page: I would recommend creating a new if `\ifintitleframe` instead of checking the page number; apart from being more semantically sound it is also more flexible because you can now have title frames on an arbitrary page (even more than one) instead than forcing it to be on the first page.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the section page template gets "called" within a frame but the background template can only be changed before starting the frame.
Also, setting flags patching `\sectionpage` probably wont work because it would set them after the background is typeset.

So, the simplest solution is to define a macro to create the section **frame** (instead of page) so you can inject the background-changing code before starting the frame.

First let's introduce few macros to change the background:

```
\newcommand{\setslidebg}{
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
        \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,8) rectangle(0.8,8.3);
        \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (0.9,8) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8.3);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
\newcommand{\setsecbg}{
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
      \node {Something else};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}    
}
\newcommand{\settitlebg}{
     \setbeamertemplate{background}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
          \fill[color=MedianBrown] (0,1.5) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
          \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,0.1) rectangle(3.45,1.4);
          \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (3.55,0.1) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.4); 
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }   
}

\setslidebg
```

where you can replace the tikzcode in `\setsecbg` to produce the desired graphics.

Then you can simply create the macros `\titleframe` and `\sectionframe` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\titleframe}{
  \settitlebg
  \frame{\maketitle}
  \setslidebg
}

\newcommand{\sectionframe}{
  \setsecbg
  \frame{\sectionpage}
  \setslidebg
}
```

so now you can just write `\titleframe` instead of `\frame{\maketitle}` and have your backgrounds set accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem in designing [my beamer themes](https://github.com/lvjr/theme). At last I found a solution: use `adjustbox` package to make your title page and section page pictures fill the whole page.

Inside your title/section page templates, you could use `\node` command to add title, author, date and section names. Therefore `textpos` package is unnecessary.

Also, you could use `\AtBeginSection` command to add section pages before each `\section`.

At last, `\the` commands before `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` inside `tikz` coordinates may be ommited.

```
% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,datetime,adjustbox}
\yyyymmdddate \renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}

\definecolor{MedianBrown}{RGB}{119,95,85}
\definecolor{MedianLightBrown}{RGB}{235,221,195}
\definecolor{MedianLightBlue}{RGB}{148,182,210}
\definecolor{MedianOrange}{RGB}{221,128,71}
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=MedianLightBrown}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=MedianOrange}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=MedianBrown}
\setbeamercolor*{section page}{fg=white}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
  \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,8) rectangle(0.8,8.3);
  \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (0.9,8) rectangle(\paperwidth, 8.3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
  \nointerlineskip
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=\paperwidth,center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \fill[color=MedianBrown] (0,1.5) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,0.1) rectangle(3.45,1.4);
    \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (3.55,0.1) rectangle(\paperwidth,1.4);
    \node[text width=0.8\paperwidth,right] at (4,3) {
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=8cm]{title page header}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor{title}\inserttitle%
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
    };
    \node[text width=0.2\paperwidth,right] at (1,0.7) {
      \begin{beamercolorbox}{date}
        \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate%
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    };
    \node[text width=0.8\paperwidth,right] at (4,0.7) {
      \begin{beamercolorbox}{author}
        \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor%
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{adjustbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}{%
  \nointerlineskip
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=\paperwidth,center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \fill[color=white] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,6) rectangle (1.5, 7);
    \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (1.6, 6) rectangle (\paperwidth, 7);
    \node[text width=0.8\paperwidth,right] at (1.8,6.5) {
      \begin{beamercolorbox}{section page}
        \insertsectionhead
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{adjustbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
    \vskip0.3cm
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{frametitle}
        \insertframetitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\author{Author Name}
\title{Quite A Long Title For A Simple Beamer Presentation}
\date{\today}

\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage}}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{My presentation is about\ldots}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some stuff
\item And some other stuff
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: title page and section page in a beamer theme]