# setbackgroundtemplate on title page within custom theme file

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, themes

I am working on a presentation theme for use with conference presentations. Most of our powerpoint themes use some type of background image on the first (title) slide, which I am trying to reproduce.

I can accomplish what I want by using

```
\usetheme{Mytheme}
\begin{document}
{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{MyBackground.jpg}}
\frame{\titlepage}
}
% Etc etc
\end{document}
```

This appears as I expect, with the image behind the presentation title, and only on the title slide.

What I want to do is move the use of the `backgroundtemplate` command in to the `beamerthemeMytheme.sty` file so that someone else using the theme down the road doesn't need to figure that particular command out. However, no amount of tweaking of `setbeamertemplate{titlepage} { ... }` has gotten this command to work.

I've seen [examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168757/creating-a-background-image-on-the-title-page-only-using-beamer/170118#170118) using pgfimage to accomplish this effect, but my attempts have not come out nearly as cleanly as `usebackgroundtemplate`. For example, either:

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{MyBackground.jpg}}
}
```

nor

```
{
    \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{MyBackground.jpg}}
    \setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    % ...
    }
}
```

have worked.

Is there a way to use `usebackgroundtemplate` (Or a similar command) from within a beamer style file?

Comment: Instead of adding the image to the background layer you could make it part of the title page, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170118/36296 Can you share your definition of the title page?

Comment: Another possibility is to create a custom titlepage command, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146858/36296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fantastic answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323638/36296 you could do the following little trick:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@navigation@titlepage{%
  \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}}% <-- define here the specific footline for the titlepage 
  \@nameuse{ps@navigation}}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\thispagestyle{navigation@titlepage}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! I've seen similar styles of commands (I.E `makeatletter`) used for other TeX tricks - is there any explanation of what is going on here?

Comment: @fergu See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do You don't need them in your .sty file, but because I working directly in the document, I had to add them to use @

Comment: Okay, I see. I'm trying to look up documentation on some of the other commands used (I.E `\ps@navigation@titlepage` or `@nameuse`), but my google searches are coming up short. Is there a document or page where these kinds of things are  defined?

Comment: @fergu I don't think you will find `\ps@navigation@titlepage` in any documentation, it is just defined in the above example. For `@nameuse` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126273/correct-usage-of-namedef-and-nameuse?rq=1

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz What is the purpose of the `\@nameuse{ps@navigation}`? If I remove it, everything still works fine and I don't see it's function because `ps@navigation` is not referenced after.